# Netty HTTP max content length over 10Gb

Tags: java, http, netty

I need to receive in netty(http) over 10Gb content length.
Please don't ask why :)

HttpObjectAggregator constructor accept only int parameter and and I can't setup for example 10737418240(its long).

Maybe exist any other way to do this?

netty version: 4.0.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just not use HttpObjectAggregator and handle the received HttpRequest/HttpContent/LastHttpContent by yourself. Buffering the whole request in memory sounds not really something you want to do.